# Icon for a mix of different things

Tags: android, icons

I have a setting activity (window) in my android app where I can configure different things. Each setting category has an icon. I have these categories

- Filter settings
- Territory settings
- Report settings
- Additional settings

But I struggle what may be a good icon for `Additional settings`. In there are all settings that don't fit into the other categories. What symbol could represent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally done something like this...

"More..."

so you can just use three dots as an icon.

...

This is now how iOS does it, too.